# PHP searching from fixed rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-search

I have patient table with 1000+ patient records. All records are created by 5 admins. I have separated patients in patient table using `admin_id` column. When admin "A" login then he only can see those patient that created by him. Now i wanna search patient from patient table. My search result will be only form patient records those are created by admin "A";

MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    patient
WHERE
    admin_id = 36 AND fname LIKE '%test%'
        OR email LIKE '%test%'
        OR mobile LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

(Here I get result from all records but I need only from where admin_id = 36.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put around the OR close a parentheses () so that the expression only is true when `admin_id` is 36 and the rest also is true

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    patient
WHERE
    admin_id = 36 AND (fname LIKE '%test%'
        OR email LIKE '%test%'
        OR mobile LIKE '%test%')
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    patient
WHERE
    (admin_id = 36 AND fname LIKE '%test%')
        OR (email LIKE '%test%')
        OR (mobile LIKE '%test%')
ORDER BY ID DESC
```